# Change theme of selector within WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview, spinner, dropdown, app-themes

**I want to be able to change the theme of the selector dialog that appears natively inside a WebView in an Android app.**

I have managed to change the background color and the radio button color but **I don't manage to change the text color.**

I do not have access to the web view element, because it opens in a SDK so I was hoping to be able to do it by changing the right parameters in my App theme.
To be clear, I have an app -> that uses a SDK -> that opens a WebView -> that opens a selector

[image]

Comment: cool stuff patri